# CONVERT to CHAR cause index on VARCHAR column doesn't work

Tags: mysql, database-performance

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a = '1';
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a = CONVERT(1, CHAR);
```

Column a is VARCHAR type, and I have already created an index on it. The first one uses index but the second one doesn't. Any Clue on this?

I suspect that maybe MySQL takes CHAR and VARCHAR as two different types, so I changed column a to CHAR, and the index doesn't work either.

Comment: How did you change type of the column?

Comment: this is a normal db engine behavior .. if you perform  function on a column  the index is not used ..  ..using char you use to differnt kind of data type and the index  can't be used.. try convert to varchar ..

Comment: I didn't perform any function on a column. And I have changed the column datatype to CHAR, it should be the same as converted value, but the index still can't be used.

Comment: @Neo How do you know the index is not used? When you run an `EXPLAIN` on that query do you get "Using index" at the end? If not, can you provide the full `CREATE TABLE` syntax of your table and your full `SELECT` statement? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @scaisEdge - the indexed column is not inside the function call, so your comment should not be relevant.  `CONVERT(...)` should be a constant, converted at compile time, and should be `'1`', but _may_ have a different charset/collation.  And _that_ difference prevents use of `INDEX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION` problem.  Please provide:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
how you are connecting to the database
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
```

Probably the answer involves changing the `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT(1, CHAR  charset utf8)
```

What is the *real* query; there may be some other approach that is better for your situation.  Using `CONVERT` is a kludge; let's go to the need for it.

To see the conversion(s), do

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
```